# Error setting up pbuilder following Ubuntu Wiki. How to set it up?

Tags: 20.04, application-development, pbuilder

I am setting up my machine for Ubuntu development. I am following [Ubuntu Development Beginnings](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BeginnersTeam/FocusGroups/Development/Devbeginnings#Thorough%20Install:%20Ubuntu%20Development%20Tools), but while running `sudo pbuilder create` command I am getting below error:

```
$ sudo pbuilder create

I: Distribution is devel.
I: Current time: Thu Jul  9 22:23:59 IST 2020
I: pbuilder-time-stamp: 1594313639
I: Building the build environment
I: running debootstrap
/usr/sbin/debootstrap
E: No such script: /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/devel
E: debootstrap failed
E: debootstrap.log not present
W: Aborting with an error
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue and set up pbuilder for creating a clean chroot environment in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Yes . "debootstrap --help"  command is giving me various options. like below:

Usage: debootstrap [OPTION]... <suite> <target> [<mirror> [<script>]]
Bootstrap a Debian base system into a target directory.

Comment: Scripts in `/usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/` are all named after releases (e.g. `bionic`, `focal`). Why are you on a `devel` release? ("Distribution is devel"?)

Comment: @muru Please write the solution you told me (--distribution) as an answer, and I will award the bounty.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi you had a perfectly fine answer, please undelete it. It's fine, I don't need the bounty.

Answer (score 8):

`devel` is not a version of Ubuntu. You will have to specify an Ubuntu release, e.g.

```
sudo pbuilder create --distribution focal
```

Sometimes, this might lead to certain issues with GPG keys related to PPAs. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273533/issue-with-gpg-keys-while-setting-up-a-proot-environment) for more information.